# How to apply two regex back to back

Tags: java, regex

Say I have `regex1` and `regex2`. I want to apply `regex1` to `text1` and then apply `regex2` to the result. Is there a way of during this without using the java method twice?

I know I can do

```
text1 = text1.replaceAll(regex1,””).replaceAll(regex2,””);
```

But is there a way to do it all in one method call? Like

```
text1 = text1.replaceAll(regex1+"|"+ regex2,””);//this of course does not work
```

Comment: I answered as community wiki before seeing that you're already chaining. That's the canonical answer -- what's wrong with it? Why are you trying to avoid this?

Comment: I am just curious about the power of regex. They seem fun to use. So, I am just curious.

Answer (score 1):

No way to automatically combine two chained `replaceAll(regex,"")` into a single `replaceAll(regex,"")`.

Example of why not: `"bob".replaceAll("o","").replaceAll("bb","")`.
The second only removes the two `b`'s if the first has removed the `o`.

You can manually merge them, because you can see how they might interact, e.g. `"bob".replaceAll("o|bo*b","")`, but combining two arbitrary regex's is not possible.